Rigged Character - Knees Bend Outwards

Technically, the rig works as intended.
The knees behave in unexpected ways.
I adjusted the rig several different ways.
The knee behavior remains.

Rigify sometimes does this when you change the hips and knees of the metarig to some bowlegged config.
To prevent this from happening and to force the generated rig to bend at the local x axis of the bone, you can select the bone in the metarig in pose mode, go to the "Bone" tab and open the "Rigify Type" submenu.
There change the "Rotation Axis" from "automatic" to "X manual".
After re-generating the rig, the leg should bend around the bones X axis.


⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐ The recommended solution is applied. The "knees" of rigged model behave as expected.
